# Time taken to load a uiscrollview

Tags: ios

I am trying to find the time taken for a uiscrollview to be displayed on a screen. I have a uibutton which when clicked creates a label with a very long text and adds it to a scrollview. Then the scrollview is added as a subview to self.view. I need to know the time taken for the scrollview to be displayed on the screen. 
Please help. Thanks in advance. Code below

```
- (IBAction)clickeMe:(id)sender {
    self.start=[NSDate date];

    NSString *text="a very long text";    

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];


    NSRange range1 = NSMakeRange(100, 300);
    [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}
                            range:range1]; 


    UILabel *label1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 700, 1000)];
    [label1 setAttributedText:attributedText];
    [label1 setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label1 sizeToFit];
    scrollviewtest *scrollview=[[scrollviewtest alloc]init];

    scrollview.frame=CGRectMake(10, 50, 700, 1000);
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(label1.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize labelSize = [label1 sizeThatFits:maxSize];

    [scrollview addSubview:label1];
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(700, labelSize.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
    [self performSelector:@selector(viewLoaded) withObject:nil];

}

-(void)viewLoaded
{
    NSLog(@"[viewloaded]");
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [self.start timeIntervalSinceNow];

    NSLog(@"time taken is %f",fabs(timeInterval));

}
```

The problem with the above code is that viewLoaded is actually getting called before the scrollview appears on the screen.

Comment: Try it out with some code and then we can help you out much better.

Comment: Do you want to know the time taken for creating that long label?

Comment: yes I want to know the time taken to display the label inside the scrollview one the screen

Comment: Try to call performSelectorOnMainThread instead of performSelector and you are done.   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(viewLoaded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: Tried using  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(viewLoaded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; but doesn't work

Comment: Hmmm,, Weird it should work, ok then try to call the method simple like [self viewLoaded]; and not any perform selector as you are not passing any objects with the method now anywayz.

Comment: @mAc thanks for your response, but still the method gets called before the view is displayed on screen

Comment: No, I was not able to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Save the time before loading your stuff, then save the time when finished loading.
Make a substract then you have your loading time.

It's like php or other languages.

Comment: I have tried this, but the selector is getting called before the view appears on the screen